# Bedeutung von Überziehen

Tags: meaning

Ich lerne Deutsch. Kann mir bitte jemand erklären was *Überziehen* in der Finanzliteratur (Banken und Kontobilanz) bedeutet?

Comment: Hast Du die Bedeutung 3a im Duden gesehen? https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ueberziehen_bedecken_heimsuchen

Comment: Es bedeutet dasselbe wie die wörtliche Übersetzung ins Englische "to overdraw"

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%BCberziehen#Verb_2

Comment: @tofro. Eher umgekehrt.

Comment: Finanzielle Wörter sind extrem untrivial auf Deutsch, es gibt viele ähnliche Wörter. Google Translate gibt regelmäßig falsche Übersetzugen. Mein Vorschlag: *leave open*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Danke bei @Marzipanherz

**1. Bedeutung:**

von etwas (was einem zusteht) zu viel in Anspruch nehmen

**2. Herkunft:**

im Bankwesen Lehnbedeutung nach englisch to overdraw

**3. Beispiele:**

den Etat überziehen
sein Konto [um 300 Euro] überziehen ([300 Euro] mehr abheben, als auf dem Konto gutgeschrieben ist)

Quelle: *www. duden.de/rechtschreibung/ueberziehen_bedecken_heimsuchen*

Comment: Schöne Antwort :) Weißt Du, dass Du auch eigene Antworten als 'akzeptiert' kennzeichnen darfst?

Comment: @Marzipanherz Danke Dir! Ich habe zwar versucht deine Kommentar als die Antwort zu nehmen, aber ich war nicht erfolgreich.

Comment: Mein Kommentar war auch nur als Hinweis für Dich gedacht: Hilfe zur Selbsthilfe :)